# CRM 2011 Entity Form fields

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

We have multiple forms added to a custom entity we created.

Is there a way for us to reference that form from the entity and than also retrieve all the fields associated with it?

Comment: Are you just looking to retrieve the fields on each individual form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, my answer is Yes you can retrieve field names not sure what you mean by referencing the form.

But I think its not a neat way of doing.

You can Query on `SystemFormSet` to retrieve the forms, `ObjectTypeCode` is the entity name and `FormXML` contains the fields displayed on form.

But if I am in your place. I won't go through such a complicated way of doing. Unless there is no other way.

**Query to retrieve form XML**

```
var formXML = (from c in SystemFormSet
              where c.ObjectTypeCode == "contact" 
              && c.Description == "A form for this entity."
              select c.FormXml).FirstOrDefault();
```